# Sharing FUSE filesystem with Samba; Mac OS X cannot access it properly

Tags: linux, macos, samba, smb, fuse

I created a simple FUSE filesystem -- read-only, and the only thing it really does to files (a bunch of audio files) is changing their names. The filesystem is hosted on a Linux server, where it works correctly -- I can ls the directories under the filesystem and play the audio files without problems.

However, I also want to share the filesystem using Samba and access it from a Mac OS X system. This does *not* work correctly. According to my server logs, it seems that OS X attempts to list the files over and over again. In the end, it takes several tens of seconds for the files to appear in Finder (which takes less than half a second on the Linux server), and opening files is incredibly slow (possibly due to the fact that my FUSE file system is working on listing the files over and over again instead of serving the files).

For the record, the server also hosts a bunch of ordinary Samba shares, which work fine on the Mac, and the server and the Mac are located together on a LAN. What is at fault here? My FUSE filesystem (seems unlikely given that it works fine in Linux), the behaviour of Finder or Samba on the Mac, or my Samba server side setup?

Comment: Is the share properly configured to reflect the read-only nature of the file system? What happens on the Linux host when you try to create a file or folder?

Comment: Yes, both FUSE and Samba are configured as read-only.